# Change chart time from UTC to IST in tradingview lightweight-chart

Tags: lightweight-charts

I plotted the ohlc data using UTC Timestamp (converted from IST). For e.g., `2021-01-01 09:15:00+05:30` => `1609472700`

In the plot, time in the x-axis shows as UTC time, not in IST, i.e., `2021-01-01 03:45`.

How to change this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a custom time zone for Lightweight Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785045/how-to-set-a-custom-time-zone-for-lightweight-charts)

Comment: I have seen this. There are two approaches mentioned in the answer. I am inclined towards the 2nd approach. However, how to solve my problem is not clear to me. A more direct answer would be appreciated.